# How to truncate using std in Varnish VCL

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to truncate a random number that I use for Varnish VCL, coming from STD vmod.
The problem is that `std.real2integer()` values are passed only to `std.round()`, that, as you can guess, can only round them :-(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not beautiful at all, but an option would be `regsub(std.random(0.0, 100.0), "\.\d+$", "");`.